# Seemingly duplicate answer by another poster

Tags: discussion, answers, exact-duplicates

In [this question](https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/317992/197118) I posted an answer. After I posted my answer (by comparing timestamps), someone else posted the same exact answer I did (albeit with a GIF to illustrate it). It is now voted up higher than my answer (the "original" one).

Is the inclusion of a GIF a good reason to post a duplicate answer to the question? From what I understand in terms of Stack Exchange rules, a minor inclusion like that would have been better posted as an edit to the original answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The entire Q&A is unfortunate since there already exists a duplicate question (which this question is now closed and points towards).

However, ignoring that, if I had caught the duplicate answer when it had less votes, I would have deleted it, with a comment for the poster to edit your answer to improve it. Unfortunately the number of votes all the answers has received has made me less inclined to delete the duplicate solution. I wish I had seen the Q&A earlier — somehow I missed it even with it being a HNQ (which is what attracted further votes).

Considering the entire question *could* be removed as it is a duplicate in itself (not saying it *will* be or it *should* be), I think in this case the best action in this case is to leave it as it is.

Comment: Oh my eyes burn with that gif.

Comment: What’s the difference if the answer has so many upvotes? If you believe that what was done shouldn’t have been done shouldn’t you still take action (or at least discuss with other Mods). Not sure what example that sets for other users. *If I don’t get caught copying someone else’s answer then it’s fine to copy someone’s answer.* Not agreeing OR disagreeing with your assessment. Just trying to understand why you wouldn’t take action.

Comment: @Josh Votes show the community thinks the post has value. It's not just moderators who see that a post is a duplicate, so if people still think the post is worth being there despite being a duplicate solution, then they are welcome to vote it up. Votes do have their part to play in decision making, with its weight dependent on the severity of the problem. In this case, the duplicate did add some value and voters decide what that balance is. Meta questions like this is a form of ‘judicial precedent’ on SE and I encourage you to provide your own answer here if you so wish to make your case.

Comment: @grg Ok. I wasn’t making a case for or against the removal  it. I just wanted to know why you felt you shouldn’t remove it. Which you have explained. Thank you!